# Форматирование разметки в AndroidStudio 3.5

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

Обновил AndroidStudio до версии 3.5 и столкнулся с такой проблемой, при форматировании текста в разметке (Ctrl+Alt+L), IDE перемещает layout, в ранних версиях таких проблем не наблюдалось. Можно отключить данную функцию, сняв галку: Rerrange Code. Но тогда IDE перестаёт форматировать текст внутри View. Может кто знает как отключить перемещение полей при форматировании кода?

UPD: По прозьбе коллег на данном ресурсе, уточнение: у нас есть разметка, например корневым будет `ConstraintLayout`, Кладём в него несколько вьюшек, Layout-ов и что я заметил любит особенно путешевствовать `include`. `Include` кладём гдето в начале файла, ничего не выделяем, дальше жмакаем `Ctrl+Alt+L`, если ничего не заметили нажимаем `Ctrl+Alt+Shift+L` и в диалоговом окне проверяем включён ли `Rerrange Code`, включаем, повторяем предыдущее действие. Итог, елементы принимаю определённый порядок, что нарушает их отображение задуманное разработчиком. Отлично можно наблюдать если у вас есть такой файл отформатированный в прошлой версии `AS` и закомичен. Если бы не `VCS` я бы не сразу понял что произошло.

Comment: у меня такая же проблема, единственное решение проблемы - ждать патч)) а пока терпеть и не причесывать код этой комбинацией

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko, то есть вы тоже считаете что это бага, а не фича? Подумываю обновиться до Canary версии

Comment: @Valeriy а можно носом ткнуть, а то я не понял что именно не так форматируется ?

Comment: @keekkenen, обновил

Comment: я думаю что это на текущий момент баг в фиче)) раньше до обновления ведь все работало как нужно? у меня во всяком случае все работало корректно)

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko, если так подумать, столь глобальную фичу они должны были бы вынести в настройки. Хотя кто их там знает... P.S. думаю стоит им в баг трекер написать, предполагаю не могли такое пропустить на этапе тестирования, скорее всего все решили что это фича. Только вот  у меня не достаточный уровень владения Английским, что бы доходчиво описать проблему. Может кто возьмётся?

Comment: я думаю что они либо не заметили этого косяка либо они выкатывали обнову уже зная о косяке. И я более чем уверен что проблема не только у нас с вами есть, и тикет в трекере уже есть я думаю :)

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko, ещё одну споймал, перестал работать Java to Kotlin конвёртер

Comment: что значит перестал работать? он и так не особо корректно работал))

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko, от слова совсем. Вставляю код, появляется окошко с предложением, соглашуюсь иии... ничего.

Comment: @Valeriy да, пока не разобирался, но с разными стилями (индивидуальным и проектным), действительно сортировка разная, в первом случае ничего не меняется, во второй - как в описанном случае

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тоже столкнулся с такой проблемой. В настройка -> Code Styles -> XML в шаблонах помимо Default появился Default copy, выбрав который проблему решил. Доступные для настройки в графическом интерфейсе настройки у них особо не отличаются, но если экспортировать файлы отличаются капитально. Не дошли пока руки разобраться что к чему. Посмотрите, если ли у вас такой стиль, ибо не уверен появился он сам или я его создал. Еще рекомендуют в комментах сделать следующее:

> Там же, на вкладке Android (возможно переход на вкладкуне обязателен),
>   справа есть текск синего цвета (Set from...), жмакаем -> Predefined
>   Style -> Android. Apply.

Вполне верю, что может помочь. Если нет, попробуйте мой конфиг(Это экспорт настроек стиля XML кода. Сохранить как .xml и импортировать на соответствующей вкладке настроек):

```html
<code_scheme name="Default copy" version="173">
  <JavaCodeStyleSettings>
    <option name="SPACE_AFTER_CLOSING_ANGLE_BRACKET_IN_TYPE_ARGUMENT" value="true" />
    <option name="DO_NOT_WRAP_AFTER_SINGLE_ANNOTATION" value="true" />
    <option name="BLANK_LINES_AROUND_INITIALIZER" value="0" />
  </JavaCodeStyleSettings>
  <codeStyleSettings language="JAVA">
    <option name="RIGHT_MARGIN" value="120" />
    <option name="KEEP_LINE_BREAKS" value="false" />
    <option name="KEEP_FIRST_COLUMN_COMMENT" value="false" />
    <option name="KEEP_CONTROL_STATEMENT_IN_ONE_LINE" value="false" />
    <option name="BLANK_LINES_AROUND_CLASS" value="0" />
    <option name="BLANK_LINES_AROUND_METHOD_IN_INTERFACE" value="0" />
    <option name="BRACE_STYLE" value="5" />
    <option name="ELSE_ON_NEW_LINE" value="true" />
    <option name="WHILE_ON_NEW_LINE" value="true" />
    <option name="ALIGN_MULTILINE_CHAINED_METHODS" value="true" />
    <option name="ALIGN_MULTILINE_PARAMETERS_IN_CALLS" value="true" />
    <option name="ALIGN_MULTILINE_ASSIGNMENT" value="true" />
    <option name="ALIGN_MULTILINE_TERNARY_OPERATION" value="true" />
    <option name="ALIGN_MULTILINE_EXTENDS_LIST" value="true" />
    <option name="ALIGN_MULTILINE_METHOD_BRACKETS" value="true" />
    <option name="ALIGN_MULTILINE_ARRAY_INITIALIZER_EXPRESSION" value="true" />
    <option name="SPACE_BEFORE_METHOD_CALL_PARENTHESES" value="true" />
    <option name="SPACE_BEFORE_METHOD_PARENTHESES" value="true" />
    <option name="SPACE_BEFORE_ARRAY_INITIALIZER_LBRACE" value="true" />
    <option name="CALL_PARAMETERS_WRAP" value="1" />
    <option name="METHOD_PARAMETERS_WRAP" value="1" />
    <option name="EXTENDS_LIST_WRAP" value="1" />
    <option name="EXTENDS_KEYWORD_WRAP" value="1" />
    <option name="THROWS_KEYWORD_WRAP" value="1" />
    <option name="METHOD_CALL_CHAIN_WRAP" value="1" />
    <option name="TERNARY_OPERATION_WRAP" value="1" />
    <option name="KEEP_SIMPLE_BLOCKS_IN_ONE_LINE" value="true" />
    <option name="KEEP_SIMPLE_METHODS_IN_ONE_LINE" value="true" />
    <option name="KEEP_SIMPLE_LAMBDAS_IN_ONE_LINE" value="true" />
    <option name="KEEP_SIMPLE_CLASSES_IN_ONE_LINE" value="true" />
    <option name="KEEP_MULTIPLE_EXPRESSIONS_IN_ONE_LINE" value="true" />
    <option name="ARRAY_INITIALIZER_WRAP" value="1" />
    <option name="ASSIGNMENT_WRAP" value="1" />
    <option name="DOWHILE_BRACE_FORCE" value="1" />
    <option name="SPACE_BEFORE_ANOTATION_PARAMETER_LIST" value="true" />
    <option name="ENUM_CONSTANTS_WRAP" value="1" />
    <option name="WRAP_ON_TYPING" value="1" />
    <indentOptions>
      <option name="SMART_TABS" value="true" />
    </indentOptions>
    <arrangement>
      <rules>
        <section>
          <rule>
            <match>
              <ENUM>true</ENUM>
            </match>
          </rule>
        </section>
        <section>
          <rule>
            <match>
              <AND>
                <FIELD>true</FIELD>
                <FINAL>true</FINAL>
                <PUBLIC>true</PUBLIC>
                <STATIC>true</STATIC>
              </AND>
            </match>
          </rule>
        </section>
        <section>
          <rule>
            <match>
              <AND>
                <FIELD>true</FIELD>
                <FINAL>true</FINAL>
                <PROTECTED>true</PROTECTED>
                <STATIC>true</STATIC>
              </AND>
            </match>
          </rule>
        </section>
        <section>
          <rule>
            <match>
              <AND>
                <FIELD>true</FIELD>
                <FINAL>true</FINAL>
                <PACKAGE_PRIVATE>true</PACKAGE_PRIVATE>
                <STATIC>true</STATIC>
              </AND>
            </match>
          </rule>
        </section>
        <section>
          <rule>
            <match>
              <AND>
                <FIELD>true</FIELD>
                <FINAL>true</FINAL>
                <PRIVATE>true</PRIVATE>
                <STATIC>true</STATIC>
              </AND>
            </match>
          </rule>
        </section>
        <section>
          <rule>
            <match>
              <AND>
                <FIELD>true</FIELD>
                <PUBLIC>true</PUBLIC>
                <STATIC>true</STATIC>
              </AND>
            </match>
          </rule>
        </section>
        <section>
          <rule>
            <match>
              <AND>
                <FIELD>true</FIELD>
                <PROTECTED>true</PROTECTED>
                <STATIC>true</STATIC>
              </AND>
            </match>
          </rule>
        </section>
        <section>
          <rule>
            <match>
              <AND>
                <FIELD>true</FIELD>
                <PACKAGE_PRIVATE>true</PACKAGE_PRIVATE>
                <STATIC>true</STATIC>
              </AND>
            </match>
          </rule>
        </section>
        <section>
          <rule>
            <match>
              <AND>
                <FIELD>true</FIELD>
                <PRIVATE>true</PRIVATE>
                <STATIC>true</STATIC>
              </AND>
            </match>
          </rule>
        </section>
        <section>
          <rule>
            <match>
              <AND>
                <METHOD>true</METHOD>
                <STATIC>true</STATIC>
              </AND>
            </match>
          </rule>
        </section>
        <section>
          <rule>
            <match>
              <AND>
                <INITIALIZER_BLOCK>true</INITIALIZER_BLOCK>
                <STATIC>true</STATIC>
              </AND>
            </match>
          </rule>
        </section>
        <section>
          <rule>
            <match>
              <AND>
                <FIELD>true</FIELD>
                <FINAL>true</FINAL>
                <PUBLIC>true</PUBLIC>
              </AND>
            </match>
          </rule>
        </section>
        <section>
          <rule>
            <match>
              <AND>
                <FIELD>true</FIELD>
                <FINAL>true</FINAL>
                <PROTECTED>true</PROTECTED>
              </AND>
            </match>
          </rule>
        </section>
        <section>
          <rule>
            <match>
              <AND>
                <FIELD>true</FIELD>
                <FINAL>true</FINAL>
                <PACKAGE_PRIVATE>true</PACKAGE_PRIVATE>
              </AND>
            </match>
          </rule>
        </section>
        <section>
          <rule>
            <match>
              <AND>
                <FIELD>true</FIELD>
                <FINAL>true</FINAL>
                <PRIVATE>true</PRIVATE>
              </AND>
            </match>
          </rule>
        </section>
        <section>
          <rule>
            <match>
              <AND>
                <FIELD>true</FIELD>
                <PUBLIC>true</PUBLIC>
              </AND>
            </match>
          </rule>
        </section>
        <section>
          <rule>
            <match>
              <AND>
                <FIELD>true</FIELD>
                <PROTECTED>true</PROTECTED>
              </AND>
            </match>
          </rule>
        </section>
        <section>
          <rule>
            <match>
              <AND>
                <FIELD>true</FIELD>
                <PACKAGE_PRIVATE>true</PACKAGE_PRIVATE>
              </AND>
            </match>
          </rule>
        </section>
        <section>
          <rule>
            <match>
              <AND>
                <FIELD>true</FIELD>
                <PRIVATE>true</PRIVATE>
              </AND>
            </match>
          </rule>
        </section>
        <section>
          <rule>
            <match>
              <FIELD>true</FIELD>
            </match>
          </rule>
        </section>
        <section>
          <rule>
            <match>
              <INITIALIZER_BLOCK>true</INITIALIZER_BLOCK>
            </match>
          </rule>
        </section>
        <section>
          <rule>
            <match>
              <CONSTRUCTOR>true</CONSTRUCTOR>
            </match>
          </rule>
        </section>
        <section>
          <rule>
            <match>
              <AND>
                <ABSTRACT>true</ABSTRACT>
                <METHOD>true</METHOD>
              </AND>
            </match>
          </rule>
        </section>
        <section>
          <rule>
            <match>
              <METHOD>true</METHOD>
            </match>
          </rule>
        </section>
        <section>
          <rule>
            <match>
              <INTERFACE>true</INTERFACE>
            </match>
          </rule>
        </section>
        <section>
          <rule>
            <match>
              <AND>
                <CLASS>true</CLASS>
                <STATIC>true</STATIC>
              </AND>
            </match>
          </rule>
        </section>
        <section>
          <rule>
            <match>
              <CLASS>true</CLASS>
            </match>
          </rule>
        </section>
      </rules>
    </arrangement>
  </codeStyleSettings>
  <codeStyleSettings language="XML">
    <arrangement>
      <rules>
        <section>
          <rule>
            <match>
              <AND>
                <NAME>xmlns:android</NAME>
                <XML_ATTRIBUTE />
                <XML_NAMESPACE>^$</XML_NAMESPACE>
              </AND>
            </match>
          </rule>
        </section>
        <section>
          <rule>
            <match>
              <AND>
                <NAME>xmlns:.*</NAME>
                <XML_ATTRIBUTE />
                <XML_NAMESPACE>^$</XML_NAMESPACE>
              </AND>
            </match>
            <order>BY_NAME</order>
          </rule>
        </section>
        <section>
          <rule>
            <match>
              <AND>
                <NAME>.*:id</NAME>
                <XML_ATTRIBUTE />
                <XML_NAMESPACE>http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android</XML_NAMESPACE>
              </AND>
            </match>
          </rule>
        </section>
        <section>
          <rule>
            <match>
              <AND>
                <NAME>.*:name</NAME>
                <XML_ATTRIBUTE />
                <XML_NAMESPACE>http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android</XML_NAMESPACE>
              </AND>
            </match>
          </rule>
        </section>
        <section>
          <rule>
            <match>
              <AND>
                <NAME>name</NAME>
                <XML_ATTRIBUTE />
                <XML_NAMESPACE>^$</XML_NAMESPACE>
              </AND>
            </match>
          </rule>
        </section>
        <section>
          <rule>
            <match>
              <AND>
                <NAME>style</NAME>
                <XML_ATTRIBUTE />
                <XML_NAMESPACE>^$</XML_NAMESPACE>
              </AND>
            </match>
          </rule>
        </section>
        <section>
          <rule>
            <match>
              <AND>
                <NAME>.*</NAME>
                <XML_ATTRIBUTE />
                <XML_NAMESPACE>^$</XML_NAMESPACE>
              </AND>
            </match>
            <order>BY_NAME</order>
          </rule>
        </section>
        <section>
          <rule>
            <match>
              <AND>
                <NAME>.*</NAME>
                <XML_ATTRIBUTE />
                <XML_NAMESPACE>http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android</XML_NAMESPACE>
              </AND>
            </match>
            <order>ANDROID_ATTRIBUTE_ORDER</order>
          </rule>
        </section>
        <section>
          <rule>
            <match>
              <AND>
                <NAME>.*</NAME>
                <XML_ATTRIBUTE />
                <XML_NAMESPACE>.*</XML_NAMESPACE>
              </AND>
            </match>
            <order>BY_NAME</order>
          </rule>
        </section>
      </rules>
    </arrangement>
  </codeStyleSettings>
</code_scheme>
```

Comment: У меня такого параметра нет, только Default. Что это за файл? Но у меня вылечилось инным способом. Там же, на вкладке Android (возможно переход на вкладкуне обязателен), справа есть текск синего цвета (Set from...), жмакаем -> Predefined Style -> Android. Apply.

Comment: Это экспорт настроек стиля XML кода. Сохранить как .xml и импортировать на соответствующей вкладке настроек. Добавлю в ответ ваш вариант